# Should I be storing all my Vue methods and data in one file?

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently using Vue on my web app for object oriented form validation, so that all I need is back-end validation and vue takes care of the rest.

This means that if my app has a lot of forms, forms that are mostly just page specific, I end up with a lot of methods and data in my Vue instance.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#mainDiv',

    data: {
        profile_text: '',
        name: ''
        //LOTS OF DATA THAT I'M LEAVING OUT
        errors: new Errors()
    },


    methods: {
        onSubmitSettings() {
            axios.post('/settings', this.$data)
                .then(response => alert('Success!'))
                .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
        },
        onSubmitCreate() {
            axios.post('/subchannel/create', this.$data)
                .then(response => alert('Success!'))
                .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors));
        }, 
        //LOTS OF METHODS THAT I'M LEAVING OUT
    }
});
```

and this is all stored in one JS file.

Should I keep doing it like this? Or should I be storing methods/data meant for only one page to be stored on that page somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the code you shared is your main/root Vue instance, it probably is a bad practice to put all these in a single component.

Ideally, your code should have segregation of components between **views** and **components**. **views** are like individual pages which contain most of the business logic whereas **components** are reusable items like checkboxes, lists, inputs, etc..

The reasons for dividing the app into smaller views are:

- Putting everything in a root instance will make your components less-reusable. They are depending on some sort of global state.
- This makes modifications harder to track; overall making code less maintainable within the team.
- Splitting into smaller views/components will allow you to use other ecosystem tools like **vue-router** which will further help in maintaining URLs, URL history, etc.
- Segregation into smaller components will enable Vue.js to better track change detection producing efficient and performant view updates. UI updates become significantly faster.

> In a nutshell, it is about following classical software engineering principles like **SOLID**, **loose coupling**, etc. This, in general, is not just confined to Vue.js.